# What does file[i] === 10 mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to get my head around this piece of code. I understand what it does functionally but I have trouble understanding the technical parts.

The code below gets a file as input, reads it and displays the lines as buffers on screen

```
var fs = require('fs')
var file = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2])
var offset = 0
for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
  if (file[i] === 10) {
    console.log(file.slice(offset, i))
    i++
    offset = i
  }
}
console.log(file.slice(offset, i))
```

From what I've seen is that the "file[i] === 10" splits the buffer at every new line, but I fail to understand what the number 10 means in this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who wrote it...?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm

Comment: is this for node.js? it looks like a serverside script to me. The for loop is stepping through the buffer one byte at a time, if it happens upon a line feed character(0x0a, or d10)it outputs everything since the start(or previous output) to the console

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is a valid question, with a simple solution. I don't think the author needs to get involved.

Comment: @simonzack: He may not _need_ to, but a good first step for the OP would have been doing some basic research, i.e. asking the author or consulting the documentation. Do you not agree? Further, it is in the interests of all of us to promote this practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`fs.readFileSync(filename, [options])` docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options):

> If the `encoding` option is specified then this function returns a string. Otherwise it returns a buffer.

There is no `encoding` option indicated here, so it returns a buffer.

From the [`Buffer` docs](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_index):

> **`buf[index]`**
>
> Get and set the `octet` at index. The values refer to individual bytes, so the legal range is between `0x00` and `0xFF` hex or `0` and `255`.

So, `file[i]` reads the `i`<sup>th</sup> byte of the file. `file[i] == 10` checks if the `i`<sup>th</sup> byte of the file is the value `10`.

In [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), the value 10 corresponds to `LF` line feed character used in newlines; this logic is probably meant to check for newlines in the file and output when an entire line has been read.

Answer (score 1):

The === operator in javascript means: equal value and equal type

So the value of f[i] must be 10 and exactly the number 10 that means the character LF in ascii.